# std::function as key in associative containers

Tags: c++, c++17, std-function

Is my understanding right that one can not use `std::function` as a key with neither the ordered, i.e. `std::map`, `std::set`, nor unordered associative containers, i.e. `std::unordered_map`, `std::unordered_set`?

Background is that I implement a timer driven observer, i.e. in this case the subject. I give the observers a `std::function<void(void)>` object in order to unsubscribe again. Of course the subject has to house keep which of the callbacks shall be unhooked/deleted when this unsubscription function is invoked.

So naturally I was thinking about using a copy of `std::function` as key for a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`. In the hope of function pointer like semantics I was hoping of the equal operator, a less or hash implementation for the `std::function` instantiation. The baffling thing I encountered while reading a reference/the standard is:  The `operator==` and `operator!=` is not working as expected since they are only comparing to an empty i.e. default constructed function object.

However as I read 23.14.7 and my general understanding, I should be able to use `std::function` instantiations out of the box in the mentioned containers, since they using `std::equal_to` instead of directly `==` right?

Also the identity i.e. the `std::equal_to`/total order would match two functions objects "pointing" to the same callback as equal, right?

Comment: I think `std::equal_to` would use the default `==` anyway, and since `==` only works with `std::nullptr_t` type, you can't do what you describe.

Comment: @Superlokkus Where did you see such things? I can't find any of those in [func.wrap.func](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func) (hash, less and arithmetic operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Background is that I implement a timer driven observer, i.e. in this case the subject. I give the observers a std::function object in order to unsubscribe again.

Don't do that.

Instead, return an iterator to the container where you stored the function object that the subscriber can use to unsubscribe.

---

> I should be able to use std::function instantiations out of the box in the mentioned containers, since they using std::equal_to instead of directly == right?

The generic `std::equal_to` uses operator `==` directly. There is no specialisation for `std::function`. Thus there is no difference between using `==` and `std::equal_to` in case of `std::function`.

In conclusion: `std::function` cannot be used as a key in an associative container. And there is no reasonable way to make it work with custom comparison functions either.

---

> Damn, why the hell is then std::function implementing an std::hash, a total order guaranteed less operator and even arithmatic operators?

`std::function` doesn't implement either of those.

Comment: Thats not directly feasible, since I have to translate of the thread/lifetime/sychronization bounderies of the caller, i.e. my subjects runs with boost::asio with own threads, and the caller is trying to unsubscribe from the Qt GUI thread, or via NAPI from the javascript GUI thread, plus synchronization on a boost::asio::strand.

Comment: @Superlokkus It is unclear how using `std::function` as the key would solve that.

Comment: Its just that I can omit one id for house keeping.

Comment: However please focus your answer on the general question of using std::function in ass. containers. Seems like the anwser is no, one cannot use them, altough such code would be well formed, it would be unusable.

Comment: And to give you a better picture: The unsubscription callback/function object would of course contain the instruction to first synchronize the actual unsubscription, i.e. would simply post on the contained io_context with a given strand, which deletes the observe callback in the internal container.

Comment: Ahhhh I mistook 23.14.6 as the class definition of std::function, but its the whole funcional header, it was 23.14.13.2 I was supposed to look for. Thanks

Comment: @Superlokkus If you absolutely have to return `std::function`, then simply return a function object that captures the iterator to the container, and use the captured iterator instead of the function wrapper for erasure.